# Exporting antlib.xml to jar

Tags: maven, ant, jar, export

Hi everyone,
            I would like to export my `antlib.xml` to my .jar file using `maven` but I am not sure how to go about doing this. Can someone lead me into the right direction of handling this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming `antlib.xml` is a file in your maven project and `my .jar` is the artifact created by the project, and by `export` you mean you want the `antlib.xml` to be available in the jar, then you can do this by placing it in `src/main/resources` folder of your project. I doubt if it is that, so can you elaborate?

Comment: @Raghuram That's the answer to the question. It's odd that someone would use Maven to build an ANT artifact....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `antlib.xml` is a file in your maven project and `my.jar` is the artifact created by the project, and by export you mean you want the `antlib.xml` to be available in the jar, then you can do this by placing it in `src/main/resources` folder of your project.

Comment: Blatant copy of [@Raghuram](http://stackoverflow.com/users/254643/raghuram) 's answer to close the question. Dear cclerville, could you accept this answer (placed in the community wiki, I don't get credit).